# Convert.IsDBNull in .NET Core

Tags: ado.net, .net-core, sqldatareader

Looks like `Convert.IsDBNull` has been removed from .NET Core.
What is the new way of doing it?

I have a line that looks like this:

```
var str = Convert.IsDBNull(reader[0]) ? string.Empty : reader[0].ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

It's in the [latest code](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/d25179596005a8df55bd46011a497c05dac7a54a/src/mscorlib/shared/System/Convert.cs#L176), and can be located on [APIsOf.Net](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Convert.IsDBNull(Object)), so you probably didn't reference right package or using version of the .Net Core **less than `2.0`**. See also: [issue on Github](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/9328)

Default implementation:

```
public static bool IsDBNull(object value)
{
    if (value == System.DBNull.Value) return true;
    IConvertible convertible = value as IConvertible;
    return convertible != null ? convertible.GetTypeCode() == TypeCode.DBNull : false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `Imports System.Convert` to the top of your file. Recently ran into this converting an older project into a net standard nuget package.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the new way is this:

```
var str = reader.IsDBNull(0) ? string.Empty : reader.GetString(0);
```